# css image swap on mouseover flickering

Tags: html, css

Hi ive got the following code below but the images flicker when mouse is over.
Does anyone know how i can fix this?

```
<a href="#"  tagtype="StoreLink" title="Playstation 4"><img alt="" class="baseImage"      src="https://merchanttoolbox.play.com/resources/merchant/19825548/72356.jpg" title="" /><img  alt="" class="rollOver" src="https://merchanttoolbox.play.com/resources/merchant/19825548/72357.jpg" title="" /></a>



<style>

.rollOver {display:none;} 
.baseImage:hover {display:none;} 
.baseImage:hover~.rollOver {display: inherit;}  

</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally put the hover on the parent `a` as this will always be visible and you are less likely to encounter these sorts of issues.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bkw9t/2/)

Comment: that works great in dreamwever and my browser but not here http://www.play.com/store-preview/12b44b4f-8d0c-415d-8a67-a413ae7ad662/tester%20rollover wich is odd the first method worked but with the flickering, any idia why that maybe or how can i fix it?

Comment: @pud What CSS is being used? I can see the HTML is correct but I can't find any of the correct classes in the CSS files

Comment: I have to use plays on page builder so thats why im getting probs, ive just checked the code and its messed up the the css whats with all the &lt;br&gt??

Comment: <style>.hover .baseImage {&lt;br&gt;    display: block;&lt;br&gt;}&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;.hover .rollOver {&lt;br&gt;    display: none;&lt;br&gt;}&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;.hover:hover .rollOver {&lt;br&gt;    display: block;&lt;br&gt;}&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;.hover:hover .baseImage {&lt;br&gt;    display: none;&lt;br&gt;}&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;</style>

Comment: @pud Is the page builder a WYSIWYG editor? If so the problem is that the editor is probably trying to encode the CSS. This is a separate problem.

Comment: yes it is WYSIWYG editor, there is an option to View Generated HTML and i'm copy pasting the html and css in there

Comment: @pud I don't have much experience with these editors, but I have added another answer with a solution that may work better for you.

Comment: @pud if you can't use javascript, try removing the line breaks from the styles, this may be what the editor is trying to encode: http://jsfiddle.net/Bkw9t/5/

Comment: awesome thanks so much for all this help it was the line breaks lol just one more problem now the rollover works if you hover in and out from the bottom or the left but not if you go in and out from the right I assume that this has something to do with the hidden image being there, any ideas how to fix this

Comment: @pud Ah, no worries mate. I think the problem you are describing is because the `a` is taking up the full width of it's parent. You can fix this by adding `float: left;` see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Bkw9t/7/

Comment: @pud Also if my answer helped you, it'd be great if you could mark is as accepted. Cheers :)

Comment: i just click the tick?